# iOS Volume vs Android Volume

Tags: volume

Okay, so I'm not sure if this is just me or what. But whenever I'm listening to my headphones on my iPod, the volume is exceptionally louder than that of my Nexus 4. Mind you that I am using the same type of headphones for both. Is there a reason for this? How can I increase the volume of my Nexus to be that of my iPod? Any help or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This site is for specific programming question. What you posted above is not a programming question.

Answer (score -1):

That's part of the hardware which is a decision made by manufacturer. There are ways to amplify the output signal by using software, and there should be apps for that, but generally that would saturate the signal and amplify noise to annoying levels, which is nothing you want.

Consider also defect. Have you tried listening to other Nexus 4? Mine feels loud enough.